# Failed to install a new version of the application without deleting the previous version by changing the OS

Tags: android, flutter, apk, sign

I published an apk to my site and Apk has been signed with signatures.

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

I changed my os and build a new apk in my new os with the same signature but I couldn't install the new version without uninstalling the previous version.

Is there any solution to build an apk that if I changed my os and build a new apk in the new os, there is no need to uninstall the previous version?

> i builded an apk in windows with version: 0.0.2+5 and `signingConfig signingConfigs.release`. but when i changed my os to Linux and build a new apk with same sign key and update version to 0.0.4+8 users can not update my app without uninstall previous version

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the version in pubspec.yaml
From

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

to

```
version: 1.0.0+2 or higher
```

Comment: I also updated my version code. i builded a apk in windows with version: 0.0.2+5 and   `signingConfig signingConfigs.release`. but when i changed my os to Linux and build a new apk with same sign key and version: 0.0.4+8  users can not update my app without  uninstall  previous version

Comment: are you using same keystore in both os?

Comment: Yes I use same keystore .